# Как обратиться к кнопке в активити из фрагмента

Tags: java, android

возникла такая проблема, нужно из фрагмента сделать кнопку в активити видимой.

Пытался делать так(по классике), но не получилось:

```
    btn_back = view.findViewById(R.id.back);
    btn_back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_back.setEnabled(true);
```

Буду благодарен, если подскажите решение данной проблемы.

Логи:

> Process: com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer, PID: 13473
>                                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                            at com.example.omen.serverforcofe.Fragment_service$3.onClick(Fragment_service.java:59)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Здесь уже столько раз было про NullPointerException, поищите.

Comment: @Эникейщик, сама ошибка я понимаю о чем говорит, вопрос в том, как ее исправить в данном случае.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615926/282277 Может, поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете создать интерфейс

```
public interface IOnFragmentInteractionListener {

    void onAction();
}
```

В вашем фрагменте

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private IOnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    //some code

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NotNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof IOnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (IOnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement IOnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    //some code

    private void yourAction(){
        mListener.onAction();
    }
}
```

И в активити реализовать интерфейс

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IOnFragmentInteractionListener {

    //some code

    @Override
    public void onAction() {
        btn_back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn_back.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Логика такова, что фрагмент ничего не должен знать об активити! По факту вы говорите: "Вот я во фрагменте совершил какое-то действие и те классы которые реализуют этот интерфейс должны на этот каким-то образом отреагировать"

Этот метод хорошо подходит для любых взаимодействий между фрагментом и активити.